# Using json object values in typescript component variable?

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, dictionary, semantic-ui-react

I'm still fairly new to using typescript but I encountered a situation I don't quite know how to solve. I'm trying to take some static json data I have in my react typescript project and use it as a semantic ui component variable value.

I have a file named `socials.ts` saved in a `data/` directory, and it looks like

```
export const socials = [
  {
     "id":1,
     "media": "github"
     ...
  ...}
]
```

And then I have another component `SocialsLinks.tsx` that is suppose to display the icons as a link for each value in the socials object.

```
...
import {socials } from "data/socials"
import { Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";

export const Socials = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {socials.map((social) => (
        <a
          key={social.id}
          href={`https://${social.media}.com/${social.username}`}
        >
          <Icon name={ social.media }/>
        </a>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Obviously `<Icon name={ social.media }/>` throws a type error since the string social.media has type any, and Icon only accepts defined semantic UI strings.

I was wondering if there was a way to cast the social.media string to be a semantic UI one?
Or define types for the original json object so that it would work like this?

Comment: To get a static type you can use http://json2ts.com/ maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach,

I have created an `interface` for the record.

```
    import * as React from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    
    import { Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
    import { SemanticICONS } from "semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/generic";
    
    interface Social {
      id: number; 
      username: string; 
      media: SemanticICONS;
    }
    
    export const App = () => {
      
      const socials: Social[] = [
        {
           "id":1,
           "media": 'github',
            username: 'james'
        }
      ]
      return (
        <>
          {socials.map((social: Social) => (
            <a
              key={social.id}
              href={`https://${social.media}.com/${social.username}`}
            >
              <Icon name={ social.media }/>
            </a>
          ))}
        </>
      );
    };
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.